# How to prevent Quartus RTL Viewer from optimizing my Verilog code?

Tags: verilog, quartus

```
module temp (

    input [1:0] A,
    output [1:0] O

);

    wire w0, w1;

    nand (w0, A[0], A[1]);
    nor (w1, A[0], A[1]);
    not (O[0], w0);
    not (O[1], w1);



endmodule
```

When I do an `Analysis&Synthesis` to above code, and then go for `Tools->Netlist Viewers->RTL Viewer` ;

I see the below one,

[image]

Now, the thing is, I have to implement a circuit with using `NAND, NOR and NOT` gates only, and there, I have an `OR` statement. So, I though I can do an `OR` out of `NOR+NOT`. But, as you see, the RTL viewer optimizes(?) my code and replaces `NOR+NOT` with an `OR`. Is there a way to prevent it doing so?

Thanks.

---

edit:

[image]

Comment: Your question implies that this is a college/uni' assignment. If so, are you even required to enter your logic design as Verilog? Are you trying to use Verilog and a simulator to solve a simple logic problem instead of a sheet of paper?

Comment: @TonyM yes, it is part of a set of preliminary tasks of our digital circuits lab. Task is a 4 bit comparator using only nand nor and not gates. It is not explicitly said to write it in verilog, but it comes handy to me to use verilog instead of schematics. I did manage to display most parts with NANDs and NORs, I just need one OR gate at the very last part of design. It works when I test it, but my concern is maybe it is not accepted because it looks like I put an OR gate instead of NOR+NOT. Well, maybe I just should give up and use a graphical sketching although I hate it...

Comment: Hate it? Do it on paper and stop moaning, it'll do you the world of good :-D Seriously, I do a lot of professional digital design and I strongly recommend you do it on paper. You'll learn up far, far more than just toying with Verilog and getting it to do the thinking for you. Right way to go. I'm thinking of your skill and future income :-)

Comment: @TonyM hmmm, I would think that in professional relatively large scaled designs, an hdl is prefferable over sketching. To me, sketching of Quartus is really uncomfortable, that is why I go for a structral design in verilog. I don't understand why using verilog would be worse than hand sketching if I am doing a structral design? What is the difference between drawing cables by hand and writing it in code? Thanks btw.

Comment: 'Hmmm' no more, friend. You're not in a large design and your assignment is about learning digital logic design. HDLs abstract you from the real circuit. You can churn out unreliable rubbish circuits that superficially appear to work. Understand digital logic design, don't just become a VHDL/Verilog writer. It's probably faster and easier on paper for a tiny circuit like this than in schematic capture, which I wouldn't use. They're trying to get you to understand the building blocks fluently. It's your choice but the goal isn't to find your personally comfortable path.

Comment: @TonyM did you mean you don't use paper drawings or schematic capture? If the latter, then how do you do your designs? Always on paper?

Comment: When I first learnt digital logic, I did all designs and mental simulations in sketches then schematic because there was no cheap HDL availability. When I moved to VHDL, I wanted to understand what logic circuits my VHDL would produce. The logic circuit is what we plug in and use, not the HDL. As I understood more and more of the logic produced by HDL, I could more directly in HDL - because I was well up that learning curve. You're right at the start and need to learn that. When designing a new circuit, as with my current FPGA, I picture or sketch out the important blocks before starting.

Comment: Getting the requirements and possible logic circuit right are the hard bit. Writing the VHDL is relatively easy. If you've got the first two right, you hit no problems in the HDL. You've worked out how to relieve tight timing, how to get the gate count down to what's required. The best logic circuit is the simplest: in nearly all cases it's the easiest to maintain, has fewest failure modes and is quickest to understand. (Comment HDL well, explaining 'why' something is, not what it is - your designs need to be easily maintainable by others, not by oneself from memory.)

Comment: @TonyM thanks for sharing your experience and thoughts.

Comment: Pleasure. Like all advice, take what's useful to you and ditch what isn't. Good luck and enjoy learning :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way of stopping the gate reduction.

It's not optimisation, as it's an integral part of how Quartus interprets an HDL design and reduced to boolean equations during synthesis.

Comment: hmm, thank you for the answer. I will ask one additional question, if you don't mind. When I do a design for example in which the output of a NAND gate is directed to one of the inputs of an OR gate let's say. In RTL viewer, the name of the NAND gate is something like WideNand9 for example, so it knows it is a NAND gate. However, the bubbles are always at the other end of the cable, rather than right after the gate(AND) symbol. For my example, the buble is sticked to the input of the OR gate.  Is this also something nonchangeable?

Comment: Do you mean the inversion bubbles are on gate inputs rather than gate outputs? Edit an example picture with text into your question. By the way, cables are insulated wires. These are just (virtual) wires :-)

Comment: ok, sorry for the word `cable`. It became a little bit unrelated with the original question, however, I added the picture. Now, all the gates at left are nand gates, I did not define them as `nand` keyword in verilog, however, they are the results of some `~&` reduction operator. RTL viewer understands that they are nand gates, because it calls them `WideNandx` but, I don't understand why it moves those inversion bubbles apart from the gates.

Comment: Me neither but it does :-)